# Python pyramid logout not working goes back to the dashboard page on back button press

Tags: python, session, authentication, pyramid

[image]

This is the login dashboard that appears after successful login . When I clicked on logout it goes to the following view config where I have cleared the session and request.
**LOGOUT CODE HERE**

```
@view_config(route_name='logout',effective_principals=Authenticated,renderer='templates/index.jinja2')
def logout(request):
    DBSession.query(User).filter(User.id==request.user.id).update({"verified":'N'}) #making the verified 'N' again

    session=request.session
    headers=forget(request)
    session.invalidate() #deleting the session

    return HTTPFound(location=request.route_url('home'),headers=headers)
```

**The problem is**
when I click on the back button of the browser it goes back to the same link as in the picture. Is it because my session is not being cleared or what mistake is being here.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `http_cache=0` parameter to the view config decorator for the dashboard:

```
@view_config(route_name='dashboard', ...,http_cache=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the page comes from the browser cache. There is nothing you can do here as this is intended behavior of web browsers. There is only problem if the page comes up if you directly type it in the address bar.